Relation between the enveloping algebra $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$ and the group von Neumann algebra $W^*(G)$
Let $G$ be a Lie group. Is it true that the universal enveloping algebra $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$ of the associated Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ generates the group von Neumann algebra $W^*(G) := \overline{L^1(G)}$?
A few more details:

Generates in the sense of von Neumann algebras with $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$ acting as derivations (unbounded operators) on $L^2(G)$.
In one direction, $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$ can be realised as distributions supported at identity via:
$$ D \mapsto D \cdot \delta_e \in \text{Dist}_e(G)$$
where $D$ is a differential operator of an element of $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$. Then, $\text{Dist}_e(G)$ acts on $L^2(G)$ by convolution (using weak limits). It is then immidiate that, once 'regularised' to bounded operators, these distributions belong to the weakly closed $W^*(G)$.
I am not sure how to show the other direction, i.e. that the whole $W^*(G)$ is generated like that. I am guessing that the invariance of the Haar integral should be used somehow...

